# Derivatives Question

Tags: calculus

Been pondering over this question for quite awhile now. I'm able to get every other problem correct, but I'm not sure what it is about this one that's getting me all confused.

Derivative of $ y = \sec{((x^2 + \sin 5x)^{-2})}$

Directions Given: Find the Derivative, Do not simplify.

If anyone could help out, that'd be great.

Comment: Use the chain rule. Letting $A := x^2+\sin(5x)$, we get $\sec(A^{-2}) \tan(A^{-2}) (-2 A^{-1}) (2x+5\cos(5x))$.

Comment: I'd recommend chain rule (multiple times)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to use chain rule multiple times.

In this case, $y = f(g(h(x)))$ such that:

$h(x) = x^2 + \sin(5x)$

$g(x) = x^{-2}$

$f(x) = \sec(x)$

At this point, it's all about patience :)

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I'm pretty sure I got the answer correct hopefully... I think I was just going a little insane in the head about the repetitiveness of the chain rule in this problem.

Comment: @Gorse: You should get...$2(x-5cot(5x)csc^2(5x))tan(x^2+csc^2(5x))sec(x^2+csc^2(5x))$

Answer (score 0):

Chain rule is needed for this problem.  Recall that

- $\dfrac{d}{dx}[\sec(f(x))] = \sec(f(x))\tan(f(x))f'(x)$
- $\dfrac{d}{dx}[\sin(g(x))] = g'(x)\cos(g(x))$
- $\dfrac{d}{dx}[h(x)]^n = n[h(x)]^{n - 1}h'(x)$

Set $f(x) = (x^2 + \sin(5x))^{-2}$.  We need to use chain rule few more times to obtain the correct results.  By second and third recalled statements, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{d}{dx}[(x^2 + \sin(5x))^{-2}] &= -2(x^2 + \sin(5x))^{-3}\dfrac{d}{dx}[x^2 + \sin(5x)]\\
&= -2(x^2 + \sin(5x))^{-3}(2x + 5\cos(5x))
\end{aligned}$$